# Creating Millions Of Particles With Spheres

Tags: scripting, objects, particles

I have a scene where I need to put in millions of particles. I want to represent each particle with a primitive, for example, a meta-ball object. All the particles can share the same primitive. The locations of the particles are from somewhere else, therefore I need to import them and create the particles inside blender with python scripts.

Currently, I'm testing the following scripts:

```
 for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        bpy.ops.object.metaball_add(type='BALL', radius=0.1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(i*0.1, j*0.1, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

I input the code via the console, but this seems inefficient and freezes blender. Is there a way to create many copies of the same object more efficiently?

I also found the array modifier. The array modifier seems to be able to handle a very large number of objects without a problem. However, I'm not sure how to input arbitrary displacements for each individual copy. As in my case, each particle has its own displacement.

Comment: Suggestion.  Measure,with Python tools, the time it takes to add a simple cube versus the time it takes to  add metaballs.  Metaballs are not the least expensive computer time primitive. I am not sure if you are including render time.  Cleary a double for loop in  Python wont be as fast as some other high performance programming language.

Comment: bpy.ops is not the more efficient. There is other apis. But what do you want to do once created (animated, static, ...)? Any particular reason to use metaball?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, following this post:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/manipulating-particles-in-python/7552
I'm able to manipulate the positions of a particle system. So I created a particle system and then write in the positions. Then, I set the instance object of the particle system to be the primitive I want. I found a Nurbs sphere could work for me. In this way, I'm able to render 1 million particles with no problem.

[image: 1 Million metallic balls]